# Basic C++ question(error: expected expression '{' )

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, and I was working on this practice problem where I was asked to create a dynamic array. However, when I tried to compile the code and run on my MacBook terminal, the error popped up. I don't know exactly what I did wrong. The strange thing is when I copied the same code and ran again in CLion, it worked totally fine! Could it be something with the terminal on mac? [error message on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfl8a.png)[the same code worked fine in CLion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pV6G.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct CandyBar
{
    string name;
    float weight;
    float calory;
};

const int size = 3;

int main()
{
    CandyBar* pt = new CandyBar[size];
    pt[0]=
    {
        "Candylla",
        12.5,
        32
    };
    cout << pt[0].name << endl;
    delete [] pt;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `pt[0] = {...}` to `pt[0] = CandyBar{...}`.

Comment: Congratulations! You have just discovered one of the reasons `using namespace std;` sucks!  Poor compiler doesn't know if `size` in `new CandyBar[size];` is referring to the `size` variable defined above or the `std::size` function recently added to the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't use an image for error messages. Cut and past the sucker into the question as text. And now that I've seen the error message, my above point is NOT the bug you've run into. YET.

Comment: It looks like whatever compiler you are using does not default to a modern C++ Standard and does not allow the type of initialization you are using. Add `-std=c++11` to the command line.

Comment: Also, work to diagnose which lines.. then focus on that. For example, if the p[0] = .. is commented out, does it have the same issue? If so, why? If not, why not? Isolating the very specific problem is a good coding skill as then it allow further problem refinement .. and ask more focused questions with good/bad case comparisons, etc.